# UIActivityTypeMessage not showing

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, message

I have recently added a UIActivityTypeViewController, which according to the documentation includes SMS through the Message function. However, Message doesn't seem to appear when I create this, I can get all the other default values and exclude what I want. Do I have to create a custom UIActivity to include Message?

Comment: Are you testing the app on a iPhone? The simulator does not have support for messages.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIActivityMessage` won't show unless you include a string in the `ActivityItems` parameter of the `UIActivityViewController` `initWithActivityItems:applicationActivities:` method. Unfortunately, you can't send an image via text message using `UIActivityMessage`.